# Is commenting disabled on this site?

Tags: discussion

I can't see the comment link under the questions. I've put my comment as an answer and it's got deleted. How can I add a comment here?

Comment: You comment wasn't deleted; there was probably a message saying you don't have the reputation for it.  See here [privileges](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).  Also, I voted to close your question because it's about the site rather than about game dev.  That kind of question belongs on [meta].  Read the help section; it explains everything.

Comment: Actually your comment was an excellent answer to my question. Why didn't you put it in the answer section.

Is there a way to move my question to the meta site ?

Comment: I didn't answer because your question will inevitably be removed.  Yes, it might be moved to meta, the moderators can handle that.  But it has also already been asked on meta, so it might be deleted outright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you provided was not an answer to the question, it was a follow up question of your own:

[image]

I deleted your answer because it wasn't an answer. Further, it wasn't a good comment either because it was actually a question. So I didn't convert it to a comment.

You don't have enough reputation to comment, which is why the comment link doesn't show up. Ask and answer questions to get reputation. Then you'll be able to comment where you like. Do remember to keep comments as requests for clarification and for suggesting improvements. Not for "I'm having this problem too, what should I do". Feel free to ask a question about the problem you're having.

Comment: I'd ask this to meta but it says I need 5 reputation to be able to ask.

So I have to ask it in here...

What should I do in this given situation below?

* I have a problem and I google it.
* I found a guy here asking the same question with me.
* There is no answer to him.
* It's been a quite while since his question asked.
* I want to contact him to ask if he found the solution in that time.
* There is no contact information in his profile.
* Asking a question under the question is wrong.
* Commenting requires reputation too.
* Even if not, my question is not a comment.

So, what should I do?

Comment: It's a problem that our system doesn't handle very well unfortunately. It's a [common problem](http://xkcd.com/979/) on the internet in general. There's a number of reasons it's a hard problem to tackle, but that's not the topic here. I'll try to get the other question some attention. For now, you'll just have to wait and see.